How to change the componentA for componentA1 in a named router-outlet using a button in the componentA
I have the following application:
home.component.html:
<carrousel-component></carrousel-component>
<tab-menu></tab-menu>

In the tab-menu.component.html, which is a child of HomeComponent, I have:
<tab-a>
  <router-outlet name='tabA'></router-outlet>
</tab-a>
<tab-b>
  <router-outlet name='tabB'></router-outlet>
</tab-b>

When my application starts, I want to render ComponentA in the router-outlet 'tabA' and ComponentB to be rendered in the router-outlet 'tabB'. This part is working perfectly with the router.module.ts:
[
 {
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent,
  pathMatch: 'full',
  children: [
   {
    path: '',
    component: ComponentA,
    outlet: 'tabA' 
   },
   {
     path: 'componentA2',
     component: ComponentA2,
     outlet: 'tabA'
   },
   {
    path: '',
    component: ComponentB,
    outlet: 'tabB'
   }
  ]
 }
]

The problem is, inside the ComponentA template I have a button that, when clicked, should render ComponentA2 in the place of ComponentA in the tabA router-outlet, but I can't get this to work.
I've been trying to use the componentA button with
[routerLink] = "{ outlets: {tabA: 'componentA2'} }"

or
[routerLink] = "{'', { outlets: {tabA: 'componentA2'} } }"

And a lot others formats like the above, but I keep receiving the path not found error.
Can someone, please, help me with that?
Thanks in advance.

Hi @RonaldoA, I couldn't see in the official documentation the "outlets", Which version of angular do you use?, try to use it with array. [routerLink]="['/my/path/here']" also check the path of componentA and componentB because their have the same one.

Hi @JoelGarciaNuño, I'm using Angular 15. You can see about 'outlets' in the official Angular page https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet, but I looked up in some others places before use the feature and also couldn't figure out why, in my case, its not working. About componentA and B having the same path, this is ok cause they're being called by two diferents outlets and this part, as I said before, its working, since componentA and B are being initially correctly rendered.
